# Add time offset for mirroring via lftp

Tags: git, ftp, gitlab, lftp

I am working on a CI runner in GitLab which is supposed to transfer changed files via FTP to a development environment.

`lftp` seemed to be a good solution for doing so as it's easy to use and not overly complicated.

I am using this to transfer files:

```
lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $USERNAME_DEV,$PASSWORD_DEV $HOST_DEV; mirror -Rvpn -O $PATH_DEV --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
```

The problematic part is the `-Rvpn` parameter set, specifically the `-n`. This is supposed to mirror only newer files which will most probably work by checking file change times.

Now my repository uses the correct time but my server is one hour in advance (GMT+2 instead of +1) which will lead to a false when checking for newer files.

I could remove the `-n` but then the whole repository would be cloned, not only the changed (and therefore newer) files.

Is there any way to define a time offset for `lftp`, so it adds +1 hour to the file change date or something similar? I checked [the manual](http://lftp.tech/lftp-man.html) but did not find anything like that.

Comment: If you look at the config you can set `ftp:timezone (string)`, that could correct the value. In addition you might be able to utilize `--ignore-time`, `--newer-than=SPEC` or `--older-than=SPEC`.

Comment: I will try that in a minute. Would you add it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the manual you've linked `lftp` has an option that enables you to define the timezone for the remote site. It might be worth it to try to set it and see whenever `lftp` correctly compensates.

> ftp:timezone (string)
>
> Assume  this timezone for time in listings returned by LIST command.  This setting can be GMT  offset  [+|-]HH[:MM[:SS]]  or  any  valid  TZ  value  (e.g.  Europe/Moscow  or MSK-3MSD,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3).  The  default  is GMT.  Set it to an empty value to assume local timezone specified by environment variable TZ.

In addition it has a switch to ignore the time (`--ignore-time` which might enable you to make it rely only on file size and some switches (`--newer-than` and `--older-than`) to define a time "that matters" so you might be able to set it up in a way that not all files are transfered.